# UINavigationBar disappears on scroll

Tags: autolayout, uinavigationbar, xcode8

I have a UINavigationBar that is configured to Hide Bars on Swipe.  The Nav bar hides when I scroll down, but does not reappear when I scroll upward.  I have to tap to get the Nav bar to reappear. All views in this VC are configured via Auto Layout (no code).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this.  My scroll view was pinned to the top and bottom layout guide.  I pinned it to the top and bottom superview, and the Nav Bar's behavior was corrected.
Thanks!